# Yii2, Can't Update the letter into database

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, yii2

I was studying Yii2

I found a few problem when I want to update value into the exists records

Here it's my code for update

```
    <?php
    function UpdateValue($date_time,$svname,$tname,$path,$ttech){

    $folder='C:\xampp_x\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\web\readtext\\'.$path.'\\';
    $folder_dir=dir($folder);

    $connection = Yii::$app->db;

    while (($file = $folder_dir->read()) != false){
        $posl=strpos($file,'-');
        $posu=strpos($file,'_');
        if ($posl=='' and $posu==''){


            $name_ttech = 'app\models\\'.$ttech;

            $model_update1 = $name_ttech::find()
                ->select('No')
                ->where(['FileName' => $file]);

            if ($model_update1){

                foreach($model_update1->all() as $value_num){

                $num = $value_num->No;

                include $folder.$file;

                $command = $connection->createCommand(
                    'UPDATE '.$tname.' SET Value = '.$value.' WHERE No='.$num.',DateTimeBatch='.$date_time.',SeverName='.$svname);

                $command->execute(); 


                }

            }
        }
    }
}
    ?>
```

And the error

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUFm2.png

- I used SQL Server 2008

Thank you

Comment: `$value` looks borked to me

Comment: @Dagon , sorry I don't understand.

Comment: look at `$value`, is that what you wanted to add to the database?

Comment: "$value="3DES: $des AES-128 or above: $aes";" this is the $value from include function

Comment: if you value field is string type it needs to wrapped with quote, have you checked this case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your SQL query. You shoud use binding params via PDO, not just concatenated SQL query string. Because of concatenation values into SQL query are worst practices and leads to SQL injection.

In your error you can see that `$value` inside SQL query isn't escaped.

So example of your query should be like that

```
$db->createCommand('UPDATE {$tname} SET Value = :value 
                    WHERE No=:num, DateTimeBatch=:datetime, SeverName=:server_name', [
    ':value' => $value,
    ':num' => $num,
    ':datetime' => $date_time,
    ':server_name' => $svname,
])->execute();
```

But also, you have some unclear logic in your code. You are using both Models classes to find rows, but also QueryBuilder to update them. 
You are including some strange logic from another file, but better you can incapsulate this logic in you Model class or helper(depends in what you are doing in that class).

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use parameter binding to avoid this kind of error and security problems, e.g :

```
$connection->createCommand('UPDATE '.$tname.' SET Value = :value WHERE No=:num, DateTimeBatch=:date_time, ServerName=:svname', [
    ':value' => $value,
    ':no' => $num,
    ':date_time' => $date_time,
    ':serverName' => $svname,
])->execute();
```

Read more about [binding parameters in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#binding-parameters).

Or you could simply use an update command :

```
$connection->createCommand()->update($tname, ['Value' => $value], ['No'=>$num, 'DateTimeBatch'=>$date_time , 'serverName'=>$svname ])->execute();
```

Read more about [Yii2 update command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#update()-detail).